# concatenate elements of list into a new list depending on condition

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list with sentences.
and another list with a few words.

```
sentences=['this is first', 'this is one', 'this is three','this is four','this is five','this is six']
exceptions=['one','four']
```

I want to loop over the sentences and if a sentence ends in one of the words contained in [exceptions] concatenate with the next sentence.

result:

```
sentences2=['this is first', 'this is one this is three','this is four this is five','this is six']
```

I could not come with any plausible attempt that would be close to work.

I started with a loop, then I converted the list into an iterator:

```
myter = iter(sentences)
```

then try to concatenate the sentences and append the concatenated ones into sentence2.

all at not avail.

Last try of mine was:

```
i=0
while True:
    try:
        if sentences[i].split(' ')[-1] in exceptions:
            newsentence = sentence[i] + sentence[i+1]
            sentences[i] = newsentence
            sentences.pop(i+1)
            i = i +1
        else:
            i=i+1
    except:
        break

 print('\n-----\n'.join(sentences))
```

Somehow I have the impression I am trying it with a wrong approach.

thanks.

Comment: In your last attempt you sometimes write `sentence` when it should be `sentences`.

Comment: It works if you fix those typos.

Comment: Also, change `while True` to `while i < len(sentences) - 1` rather than using an exception to end the loop.

Comment: typo corrected. I would say my solution does not work if several sentences (more than one) end up in one of the exceptions words.

Comment: Not sure there is any value to converting the list to an iterator - in Python lists are iterable.  (e.g. you can write something like "for sentence in sentences:")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip `sentences` with a one-offset slice of itself using `zip_longest` from itertools.  This will let you perform the check, make the concatenation when needed, and skip the next iteration when not.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

sentences2 = []
skip = False
for s1, s2 in zip_longest(sentences, sentences[1:]):
    if skip:
        skip = False
        continue
    if s1.split()[-1].lower() in exceptions:
        sentences2.append(f'{s1} {s2}')
        skip = True
    else:
        sentences2.append(s1)

sentences2
# returns:
['this is first', 'this is one this is three', 'this is four this is five', 'this is six']
```

## Edit:

You need to handle case of joining multiple sentences in a row.  For that situation, you can use a flag to keep track of if you should join the next sentence or not.  It is a bit messier, but here it is:

```
sentences2 = []
join_next = False
candidate = None
for s in sentences:
    if join_next:
        candidate += (' ' + s)
        join_next = False
    if candidate is None:
        candidate = s
    if s.split()[-1].lower() in exceptions:
        join_next = True
        continue
    else:
        sentences2.append(candidate)
        candidate = None

sentences2
# returns:
['this is first',
 'this is one this is three',
 'this is four this is five',
 'this is six']
```

Here is an example that adds an extra sentence that needs chain-joining.

```
sentences3 = ['this is first', 'this is one', 'extra here four', 
              'this is three', 'this is four', 'this is five', 'this is six']

sentences4 = []
join_next = False
candidate = None
for s in sentences3:
    if join_next:
        candidate += (' ' + s)
        join_next = False
    if candidate is None:
        candidate = s
    if s.split()[-1].lower() in exceptions:
        join_next = True
        continue
    else:
        sentences4.append(candidate)
        candidate = None

sentences4
# returns:
['this is first',
 'this is one extra here four this is three',
 'this is four this is five',
 'this is six']
```

Comment: almost @James. It looks like if one sentence is composed by only ONE of those words, then it does not work. I am playing around with the code trying to solve it.

Comment: @Berlines: the line `if any(s1.endswith(e) for e in exceptions):` checks the condition of the sentence ending in any word in `exceptions`.  However, if does capture partial word matches.  I will make it more explicit so it checks whole words only.  Check the update

Comment: This doesn't work if you have two consecutive sentences with exceptions in a row.

Comment: I am going to try another approach, starting by the end, and not from the beginning of the list of sentences. It might be an idea. I will post tomorrow

Comment: I added an update to my answer to handle the case of multiple sentences ending with an word in exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an end of line character to sentences not ending with the exception words (and a space to others), join them. (and then split on the end of lines if you need to):

```
 sentences=['this is first', 'this is one', 'this is three','this is four','this is five','this is six']
 exceptions=['one','four']

 result = "".join(s + "\n "[any(s.endswith(x) for x in exceptions)] for s in sentences).strip().split("\n")
 print(result)

 # ['this is first', 'this is one this is three', 'this is four this is five', 'this is six']
```

Comment: Two issues: This won't work if any of the sentences contain a newline. `s.endswith(x)` will match a substring, not only the whole word.

Comment: @ Barmar, You are right.  If the words are always separated by spaces, we could use `s.endswith(" "+x)`. Otherwise a regular expression would be needed to cover more cases.  As for a sentence containing a new line, that seems unlikely given the problem statement but it would indeed break this solution.

Comment: The general approach is not bad, you could just use a different string that's less likely to appear naturally.

Comment: There are no newlines in the sentences, the newlines are taken out in a previous process. having a newline in the middle of an actual sentence would indicate an error

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works except in one case: when two of the sentences in a row end in an exception word. The solution is to *not* increment `i` after concatenating the two sentences, so it checks the last word of the combined sentence on the next iteration.

You also need to put a space between the sentences when concatenating them.

And instead of using an exception to detect when you reach the end, just limit `i` properly.

```
sentences=['this is first', 'this is one', 'this is three','this is one', 'this is four','this is five','this is six']
exceptions=['one','four']
i=0
while i < len(sentences) - 1:
    if sentences[i].split(' ')[-1] in exceptions:
        newsentence = sentences[i] + " " + sentences[i+1]
        sentences[i] = newsentence
        sentences.pop(i+1)
    else:
        i=i+1

print('\n-----\n'.join(sentences))
```